# What happen if a probability function does not converge?

Tags: probability-distributions, marginal-probability

Find the marginal distribution for $y_2$ given the following PDF

$$f(y_1,y_2)=
\begin{cases}
3y_1,  & \text{if } 0\leq y_2\leq y_1 \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

But when I try to find it, I end up with the following integral:

$$f_{Y_2}(y_2)=\int_{y_2}^\infty 3y_1 \, dy_1$$

and that integral does not converge. Is there any trick to solve this? or is this situation an special case?

Thanks

Comment: You should have $f_{Y_2}(y_2)$ where you have $f_{y_2}(y_2). \qquad$

Comment: The function that you called the PDF is not in fact a probability density function, for just the reason you stated.

Comment: This is not a PDF as it stands.  I suspect you mean $0 \le y_2 \le y_1 \le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually meant $0<y_2<y_1<1$, first check that you have pdf by integrating:
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^{y_1} 3y_1 \, dy_2 \, dy_1
$$
Once you've done that, marginalize out $Y_2$:
$$
f_{Y_2}(y_2) = \int_{y_2}^1 3y_1 \, dy_1 
$$
Again, check this by integrating in the $[0,1]$ interval to get $1.$

Comment: No, in my homework is  $0\leq y_2\leq y_1$. I think the way my teacher write the homework is wrong

Comment: Try integrating the joint pdf, and see if you can get $1$. If not, there's an error somewhere